# Oracle SQL function to Hive Function Conversion

Tags: oracle, function, hive, mapping

while moving data from Oracle database to Hadoop, we came across some list of oracle functions which needs to be converted to their equivalent hive function.It is like matching Oracle function to Hive function. 
Is there any list of already existing HIVE function which I refer to ? if not, how can I find at least existing hive function. 
for ex, if some of the oracle function does not exist in Hive, then how to go ahead and write UDF for that ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive we could use `show functions` to display all internal functions.

If the above function can not solve your problem, Hive also support UDF, UDAF, UDTF, to make you custom your function.
Here is the introduction: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hive-functions-udfudaf-udtf-examples-gaurav-singh

Comment: Thank you very much, I will refer the same and get back in case anything is required.